# Calculating equilibrium constant given Ka value?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

> $\ce{NH_3(aq) + H_3O^+(aq)  <-> NH_4^+(aq) + H_2O(l)}$
>
> $\ce{K_a}$ for $\ce{NH_4^+}$ is $5.6\times10^{-10}$.

I am completely lost and I have no idea how to approach this question.

Comment: Totally lost leads to totally lost.  You have to give us something to work with here.  What do you know?

Comment: I know how to find the equilibrium constant with concentrations, but I don't know how I could get the concentrations of the substances with the Ka value

Comment: try writing out the Ka expression for NH4+, then compare it to the equilibrium expression.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, I figured it out. All I had to do is reciprocate the value since Ka is the reciprocal of the equilibrium constant for that reaction.

Comment: Good job on figuring it out.